# Export/Save graphic created in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, legend, graphics

I created a legend for a Map with ArcMap 10.2.2. I converted it to graphic and want to export or save it as an image. How can I do? Can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Even without Convert To Graphics, you can copy your legend and paste it in graphics software such as Paint. Convert To Graphics on a legend allows you, for example, to Ungroup the legend (using right click > Ungroup) to its different components, and modify each separately using the Draw toolbar.

Comment: I used convert to graphic exactly to ungroup and change the size of the items. So I would copy and paste the graphic. Anyway I tried both copying it in Paint before and after converting it to graphic. In the first case the legend was copied&pasted in all its components but the items (just blank space). In the second case everything was copied but the items were no longer dots, but appeared as exclamation marks. I guess that's how they are coded...

Comment: You may instead decrease the size of your layout so it's as small as your legend, remove all other items and File >  Export away as in image.

Comment: I think that would work though I expected it to be possible in a less tricky way

Comment: Works fine for me with Paint, but what I really do is export to Adobe Illustrator in AI or even PDF format, Illustrator treats the items as vector graphics. I assume free vector graphics programs have the same capabilities.

Comment: Have you tried copying graphic dots on Paint? Didn't they appear as exclamation marks?

Comment: They get copied as I see them. Maybe make them larger and then copy, or just Print Screen and paste...

Comment: They're large enough (size=15) already. I also thought about Print Screen, but that would allow me to add the exported legend to another map, with the right size already set

Answer (score 1):

Move the map data frame outside of the layout extent and make sure the legend is inside a layout extent. Go to File -> Export Map -> Choose the desired image type -> Save

Answer (score 1):

As previously stated:   "Move the map data frame outside of the layout extent and make sure the legend is inside a layout extent. Go to File -> Export Map -> Choose the desired image type -> Save"...

...THEN...use Paint to open it up, in the IMAGE group-->Select, use Selection Shape of RECTANGULAR, then use TRANSPARENT SELECTION.  Copy, then paste in the Layout.